# how to to check two files for any lines that match another file

Tags: vb.net

I'm making antivirus script that compare signatures to file it search right now I'm only testing one file at a time to see if it works. I got it to work in python but i want to write the script in vb.net

```
    Dim fname
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    fname = OpenFileDialog1.FileName 

    Dim virus = System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Users\joeblow\Desktop\virussignatures.txt")
    Dim text = System.IO.File.ReadLines(fname)

    Dim reuslts = String.Compare(virus.ToString, text.ToString)
    If reuslts.ToString Then
        lstVirusFiles.Items.Add(fname)
    Else
        lstCleanFiles.Items.Add(fname)
    End If
```

I have try         If String.Compare(virus.ToString, text.ToString) = True Then

and         If String.Compare(virus.ToString, text.ToString) then

I even try this             If text.Contains(virus.ToString) Then

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction thank you.

Comment: You are storing virus signatures as *text*?

Comment: I think you have to go through each virus signature to test whether it appears in the target file (fname), using a looping structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
Dim fname
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Return
    'Or Throw error
End If

fname = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

Dim virus = System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Users\joeblow\Desktop\virussignatures.txt")
Dim text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fname)

Dim found As Boolean = False
For Each signature In virus
    If text.IndexOf(signature, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
        lstVirusFiles.Items.Add(fname)
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If found Then
    lstVirusFiles.Items.Add(fname)
Else
    lstCleanFiles.Items.Add(fname)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks that help me a lot I was stuck on this for awhile

Comment: if it was a correct answer please mark it as answered, it may help others too when they land on this page from search engine.